# problems with relative uri's using Zend_Test

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, root

I'm setting up unit testing for the first time on my Zend Framework app (and it's actually the first time I'm doing unit testing at all).

A problem I'm getting at the moment is that I use a view helper to include my headscripts and links:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_HeadIncludes extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    public function headIncludes($type, $folder) {
        if($folder == "full" && APPLICATION_ENV == "production") {
            $folder = "min";            
        }
        $handler = opendir(getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/". $type ."/" . $folder);
        while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if($type == "js") {
                    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/' . $folder . '/' . $file);  
                } else if ($type == "css" ) {
                    $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/' . $folder . '/' . $file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handler);
    }
}
```

This is included in each view script. When I try and run a test it fails because opendir() tries to find eg "/css/full" relative to the document root, which seems to not be the same value for tests and the application. What's the best way to resolve this? I could add in a conditional to do something different when APPLICATION_ENV = "testing", but am not sure if this would run contrary to what setting up testing is supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variable 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' is only going to be set by your web server.  You may want to be using 'APPLICATION_PATH' as a reference instead as it's more reliable across virtual hosts as well as command line usage.

Comment: Also, don't forget that if you're  using PHPUnit, you can pass in a custom bootstrap file that can help set up your environment.

Comment: One slight alteration for zend was to use APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public', but otherwise exactly the answer I needed - cheers